# How add +1 day in end date based on start date using .datepicker in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a `Start` and `End` date with validation where `End Date` cannot be grater than `Start Date` which is working fine. Now I want to set `End Date` by adding an additional day based on `Start Date` selection.

I've tried several approaches but I am not getting my result.

For e.g.,

Actual Result:

If `Start date` is 02/18/2016 than `End Date` is 02/18/2016. User can select future end date which is fine.

Expected Result:

If `Start date` is 02/18/2016 than `End Date` should be 02/19/2016.

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#enddatepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
  });
  $("#startdatepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

  $("#enddatepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#startdatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
  });
  //My current logic
  $("#enddatepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

  //Approach-1 = Sets 03/08/2016 (Don't know why)
  //$("#enddatepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date().getDate() + 1);   

  //Approach-2 = Not Working
  // $("#enddatepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date().add().day() + 1);

  //Approach-3 = Not Working
  //var enddate = $('#enddatepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  //enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 1);
  //$('#enddatepicker').datepicker("setDate", enddate);
});
```

Fiddler Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkhtq6fr/5/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkhtq6fr/6/

Code Change:

```
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  $('#enddatepicker').datepicker("setDate", d);
```